# Update POD file to the same build settings as the project it is included in

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am a junior developer who has inherited the company's iOS app.  I do not have access to the person who built it.

We upgraded to Xcode 11.2, and Swift 5.  This has caused a chain reaction of dependancy problems, which was to be expected.  Biggest problem was that we are using the Facebook SDK, and the version we were using did not support iOS 13.  So I removed FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit from the podfile, ran 'pod install', added them back to the podfile, ran 'pod install' again.  I fixed the deprecated code, and all was well.

However, then the pod for our video player broke, with about a dozen deprecated/renamed function errors.  This pod, VGPlayer, was forked by our previous developer into his own repo, where he made changes to it.  So I forked it again from his repo to our company repo, with the idea that I would fix the broken stuff, then reimport it into the main project.

The problem I'm running into is that when I clone the repo and open it up in Xcode, it's fine.  All the methods that are deprecated/renamed when I import the pod into the main project are fine, and it builds perfectly.  So I'm guessing that the pod and the main project are using different build settings, but I can't figure out what's different.  They're both using Swift Version 5.0, they both have a deployment target of iOS 11.

Any suggestions here?

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

def sharedPods

    # Wrapper 
    pod 'KeychainAccess'

    # Reporting tools
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'
    pod 'Analytics'
    pod 'Intercom'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'

    # Models
    pod 'FastEasyMapping'

    # UI Components
    pod 'MXSegmentedControl', :git => 'git@github.com:vesterio/MXSegmentedControl.git', :branch => 'master'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'Presentr'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'AloeStackView'
    pod 'VGPlayer', :git => 'git@github.com:vesterio/VGPlayer.git', :branch => 'master'

    pod 'IGListKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'SwiftGen'

    pod 'SAConfettiView', :git => 'git@github.com:vesterio/SAConfettiView.git', :branch => 'master'

end

target 'Tests' do
    use_frameworks!
    sharedPods

    # Testing
    pod 'Nimble'
    pod 'Quick'
end

target 'Monner' do
    sharedPods
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        plist_buddy = "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy"
        plist = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target}/Info.plist"
        `#{plist_buddy} -c "Add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array" "#{plist}"`
        `#{plist_buddy} -c "Add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities:0 string arm64" "#{plist}"`
    end
end
```

Comment: Copy & Paste your Podfile

Comment: You can check commit history form the previous developer into  his foked VGPlayer

Comment: Not following.  Check it for what?